# Integrate wrong for absolute value of trig function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, assumptions

I was trying to get $\int_0^1 \lvert \cos(2 \pi k x) \rvert \,\mathrm{d}x$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, and was surprised by the result (using Mathematica 10.0.1.0):

```
Integrate[Abs[Cos[2 π k x]], {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> Element[k, Integers]]
```

> ```
> (Abs[Cos[2 k π]] Tan[2 k π])/(2 k π)
> ```

```
Simplify[%, Assumptions->Element[k, Integers]]
```

> ```
>  0
> ```

```
Table[Integrate[Abs[Cos[2 π k x]], {x, 0, 1}], {k, 0, 10}]
```

> ```
>  {1, 2/π, 2/π, 2/π, 2/π, 2/π, 2/π, 2/π, 2/π, 2/π, 2/π}
> ```

```
Table[NIntegrate[Abs[Cos[2 π k x]], {x, 0, 1}], {k, 0, 10}]
```

> ```
> {1., 0.63662, 0.63662, 0.63662, 0.63662, 0.63662, 
>   0.63662, 0.63662, 0.63662, 0.63662, 0.63662}
> ```

The answer of 0 is obviously ridiculous, since the integrand is nonnegative and not identically zero. `Integrate` with specific integers seems to get it right; the relevant identity [at the bottom of this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_integrals#Absolute-value_functions) of Wikipedia's list of integrals agrees that the value should be $\frac{2}{\pi}$ for $k \ne 0$, and of course it should be 1 for $k = 0$.

A similar issue happens with $\int_0^1 \lvert \sin(2 \pi k x) \rvert \,\mathrm{d}x$: `Integrate` gives $$\frac{\text{sgn}(k) (k-\cot (2 \pi  k) \left| k \sin (2 k \pi )\right| )}{2 \pi  k^2}$$
which is indeterminant for integral $k$ but has limit 0 at each integer, but whose value should also be $\frac{2}{\pi}$ for $k \ne 0$ and 0 for $k = 0$. (Again, `Integrate` with any particular value of $k$ gets it right.)

If I use the variable `k` without any `Assumptions`, `Integrate` eventually gives up.

Am I doing something wrong here in specifying my assumptions or whatever, or is this a bug for a surprisingly simple integral?

Comment: `Integrate` gives a result that is correct only for a smallish interval of values of `k`. After that it will mess up. It cannot unravel correctly the absolute value behavior in the presence of a parameter, and does not seem to figure out restrictions on that parameter that would make the result work. As for an assumption of integrality, `Integrate` will only regard that as meaning the parameter is real valued.

Comment: Interesting. I suppose I knew that `Integrate` sometimes gives results that are only valid for a subset of parameter values, but (a) I kind of wish it would say when it's doing that and (b) I didn't know it couldn't interpret the integrality assumption.

Comment: This is now fixed, the first returns unevaluated, the second gives (Abs[k]-k Abs[Sin[2 k \\[Pi]]] Cot[2 k \\[Pi]])/(2 k^2 \\[Pi])  tested on 13.3. Though the second result cannot be Simplified.

Answer (score 2):

The problem arises because of the branch-cuts of the Tan.
Since Mathematica 8.0 doesn't integrate the indefinite Integral with Abs[...], do it with Sqrt[Sqr[Cos[...]]]

```
In[173]:= int1[x_, k_] = Integrate[Sqrt[Cos[2 \[Pi] k x]^2], x]

Out[173]= (Sqrt[Cos[2 k \[Pi] x]^2] Tan[2 k \[Pi] x])/(2 k \[Pi])
```

Plotting this, shows it has 2 k Branch-Cuts where the Tan is +-Infinity.

```
Plot[(Sqrt[Cos[2 k \[Pi] x]^2] Tan[2 k \[Pi] x])/(2 k \[Pi]) /. 
k -> 3, {x, 0, 1}]
```

At the first branch-cut at x= 1/(4 k) the functions upper limit is

```
In[129]:= Limit[(Sqrt[Cos[2 k \[Pi] x]^2] Tan[2 k \[Pi] x])/(
2 k \[Pi]), x -> 1/4/k, Direction -> -1]

Out[129]= -(Sqrt[k^2]/(2 k^2 \[Pi]))
```

The lower limit there is (Sqrt[k^2]/(2 k^2 [Pi]))
The total jump at x=1/(4 k) is therefore 1/(k Pi).
This is the same for the other branch-cuts.
Multiplied with the 2 k branch-cuts you get the right result: 
2/Pi

Mathematica didn't take into accout this in the definite integral.